# Spring Boot and Spring Session: How to control the DataSource

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-session

I'm experimenting with Spring Boot and Spring session together, specifically using JDBC.

Just adding the line in application.properties:

```
spring.session.store-type=jdbc
```

made it just work, which is nice because I happen to also have some data source properties in that file, ie

```
myapp.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/etc...
myapp.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

But I'm actually using those for my own data source with my own configuration, like so:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:credentials.properties")
public class DataSourceConfig {

@Primary
@Bean(name = "dataSource")
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "myapp.datasource")
public DataSource dataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
}
}
```

and as far as I can tell, Spring Session is creating its own data source instead of using mine. Is there a way I can get it to use mine instead?
(my real data source has some additional configs with Hikari not shown here)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Spring Session itself does not create `DataSource` but rather uses the one present in your application context, if it's the either:

- the only `DataSource` bean
- `DataSource` marked as `@Primary`

Also if you wish to use a specific `DataSource` for Spring Session (for example, if you have multiple `DataSource`s in your application) you can do that by:

- annotating `DataSource` marked as designated for Spring Session by `@SpringSessionDataSource` (Spring Session 2.0 onwards)
- providing `JdbcTemplate` bean that uses the desired `DataSource` and naming it `springSessionJdbcOperations` (Spring Session 1.x)

The Spring Session JDBC configuration capabilities and logic should be quite easy to understand from  the [`JdbcHttpSessionConfiguration`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/blob/master/spring-session-jdbc/src/main/java/org/springframework/session/jdbc/config/annotation/web/http/JdbcHttpSessionConfiguration.java).

Comment: Good to know, thanks. Is this stuff documented anywhere? It's not in the Spring Session Reference or Guides, that I could find.

Comment: Admittedly, our docs are a little short in that department. We'll try to address that in the upcoming releases.

Comment: FYI, I've opened [gh-1011](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/issues/1011) to track the JDBC config docs improvement effort.