# Springboot Session Cannot be created when 2 or more datasources exist

Tags: java, spring-boot, session, jdbc

OK - **problem** ==> 2 Datasources (or more) will cause an error when using Springboot Session.

I have a Springboot project, with different data sources for different purposes. So within said project I would like to have Spring replace the HttpSession, with the Spring-Session module's HttpSession.

The creation of the session tables is simple if you follow the guides.
But the guides and API docs say you need **JUST one** data source. And so, since I have 2 or more I get the following error:

```
2020-07-21 21:38:59.134 ERROR 171262 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatStarter  : 
Error starting Tomcat context. Exception: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException. 
Message: Error creating bean with name 'sessionRepositoryFilterRegistration' defined in class path resource 
[org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/session/SessionRepositoryFilterConfiguration.class]: 
Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'sessionRepositoryFilterRegistration' parameter 1; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with 
name 'org.springframework.session.jdbc.config.annotation.web.http.JdbcHttpSessionConfiguration': 
Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: 
No qualifying bean of type 'javax.sql.DataSource' available: 
expected single matching bean but found 2: authModelDs,secureSessionDS
```

So since it cannot decide which one to use, I have to manually configure it, except that the entire process leads you to a class called
org.springframework.session.jdbc.config.annotation.web.http.**JdbcHttpSessionConfiguration**, which is quite literally non-configurable under the given need to set your own datasource.

I have looked a bit around, and there is no way to configure the Session Filter, once it is created to replace the datasource there too.

So I am boggled: how can I set the correct datasource for the configured Spring-Session?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try marking one of the data sources as `@Primary`, or `@Qualifier` the injected instance so Spring can resolve which one to use when injecting.

Comment: Thank you Andrew S, I have used those resources also. The creation of a Session in Spring-Boot is rather deep in the works. And at some point, a class called JdbcHttpSessionConfiguration sets the data source, and it gets [all available] data sources, even if I declared one and only one as primary. So due to it finding 2 or more, it throws the error. My quest is to tell JdbcHttpSessionConfiguration to load a specific datasource. I am so busy with that right now, that I am sure it is around the corner that I will find my answer.

Comment: I am going to add some additional stack traces-

org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'javax.sql.DataSource' available: expected single matching bean but found 2: authModelDs,secureSessionDS
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveNotUnique(DependencyDescriptor.java:220)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1282)

Answer (score 1):

AHA!  Soooooo

There is an annotation that you can place on the Bean creation of your datasource, to specify that such a bean is the SpringBoot session datasource.

The annotation is - **@SpringSessionDataSource**

It is not something that is really straight forward in the documentation at all!

Props to the following Stack Overflow answer:

[Spring Boot and Spring Session: How to control the DataSource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49042664/spring-boot-and-spring-session-how-to-control-the-datasource#49052829)